# can't copy database from assets folder to external storage

Tags: android

I use the following code to copy database from assets folder to external storage:

```
private void copyDataBase(String dbPath){
    try{
        InputStream assestDB = context.getAssets().open("databases/"+dbName);
        OutputStream appDB = new FileOutputStream(dbPath,false);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = assestDB.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            appDB.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        appDB.flush();
        appDB.close();
        assestDB.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am trying it on my phone and what happens is exactly 2048 bytes are copied, and nothing is copied afterwards (my file is about 13KB). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's causing your problem, but '-1' is returned on error, not '0'. The docs imply that '0' should never be returned, but it might be possible. You could try changing the line:

```
while ((length = assestDB.read(buffer)) > 0) {
```

to:

```
while ((length = assestDB.read(buffer)) != -1) {
```

to see if that helps.

The fact that you're getting *some* output, makes it unlikely that you have a permissions (Android or file system) violation.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I don't think it worked - still stuck at 2048 bytes. I actually do have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my manifest.

Comment: another interesting observation is that when I call this method from an activity (this method is part of a SQL Helper class), the entire database gets copied.

Comment: That *is* interesting. It basically says that there's likely nothing really wrong with the code here and that the problem is elsewhere. It sounds like whatever process or thread that is running this method is ending before this method is complete.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it made me think about the setup I was using to copy the files around. The problem was in the database helper class; it did not copy the file over an automatically created empty database. I fixed the class eventually and it's all better now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission set in your manifest. Then, have a look at using `context.openFileOutput(String, int)` and `Environtment` for your desired file directory.

The Android training guides provide a good document on how to correctly read and write files.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html